# Action Script 3. Randomly moving items UP and DOWN from array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, random

So I'm creating game similar like this: [example](http://zaidimai.mama.lt/kiskis-nori-kakavos)

I have an array of items already added to 4 holes. I need to make that these items randomly moved up (+100px) and down(-100px).

I have added to all holes for 6 items:

```
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
        holeArr[0].inside.addChild(itemsArr[4][i]);
        holeArr[1].inside.addChild(itemsArr[5][i]);
        holeArr[2].inside.addChild(itemsArr[6][i]);
        holeArr[3].inside.addChild(itemsArr[7][i]);
        }
```

How can I make them randomly move up (+100px) and down(-100px)? I started, but I don't know what to do next... Could you help me, please?

```
function randomSpawn() {
        for(var i:uint = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
            itemsArr[4][i].x += 100;
            itemsArr[5][i].x += 100;
            itemsArr[6][i].x += 100;
            itemsArr[7][i].x += 100;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To move an item randomly up/down +-100 pixels:

```
var distance = Math.round(Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 100;
mySprite.y += distance;
```

To animate it with Tweenlite

```
var newPosY = mySprite.y;
newPosY += Math.round(Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 100;
TweenLite.to(mySprite,1,{y:newPosY});
```

The simplest way to select a random item from an array

```
var index = Math.round(Math.random * (myArray.length - 1));
var myRandomItem = myArray[index];
```

Comment: `itemsArr[4][i].x += 100;` -> `itemsArr[4][i].x = STARTING_POINT + distance;`.. And I don't get the idea of having for loop from 0 to 6, and this strange itemsArr with indexes 4,5,6 and 7.. Anyways, that's another problem, Pier provided proper solution - the `distance` variable will be something between -100 and 100. Be careful to provide a starting point, otherwise it could constantly move up and down (starting at 0, += 100 = 100; += 100 = 200; += 50 = 250).

Comment: This is not exact what I need. I need to get 1 random item for array and move It for +/- 100 up/down. And I need to make It a bit slower, I made now for 1 item, but It so fast changing coordinates.

Comment: Start using Tweener. And start defining questions better. Pier answered your particular question.

Comment: Like Andrey said, if you need animation use a tween engine like Tweener or TweenLite. The logic still applies.